# Replacing certain characters of string in column (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database that features a 'name' column with values such as:

- SDP3973455/1
- 101390375/2
- SDP4608677
- 105859492/1
- 104295947

As you can see, some values have the characters 'SPD' in front and some values have '/1 or /2' at the end of the string. I want to keep only the numbers inbetween these characters.
So 'SDP3973455/1' would be replaced with '3973455' and '105859492/1' would be replaced with '105859492'.

I have tried using the following query but I get this message '0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 2171368 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0':

```
UPDATE myTable
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'SDP', '');
```

If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated. Also if you can figure out how to delete '/1' or '/2' that would be wonderful.

Comment: It either `SDP` or `SPD`. Please correct where appropriate.

Comment: If your MySQL is version 8 (or up) consider using [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Try escaping `name` with backticks since it is a [MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would suggest that your column has no `'SPD'` in it.

One problem might be intervening characters.  Presumably, this query returns no rows:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where name like '%SPD%';
```

You could then try a more general pattern:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where name like '%S%P%D%';
```

Or perhaps the characters are from an extended character set.